# Cannot change UIView background color and UILabel text color iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uilabel

I've looked at many posts and none seem to help with the current issue I'm experiencing. I am trying to change the UIView background color and UILabel text color programmatically on a button click. They are all connected in the interface builder. What I did was open the ViewController.h file next to the Main.storyboard and clicked and dragged to connect the view (backgroundView) and label (letterR).

If anyone can see what I am doing wrong that would be great thanks!

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{

    IBOutlet UIView *backgroundView;
    IBOutlet UILabel *letterR;
}

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController

static int flag = 0;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (IBAction)ButtonClick:(id)sender {

    if(flag == 0){

        flag = 1;
        letterR.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }

    else if(flag == 1){

        flag = 0;
        letterR.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:1 blue:1 alpha:1];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Your code looks correct. You should log letterR and backgroundView in your buttonClick: method to see if they are nil.

Comment: If they are nil what should I set them to?

Comment: This is what I get when I print them using NSLog:

2014-11-26 15:18:18.358 Rave[3923:340203] Letter R: <UILabel: 0x798d1680; frame = (65 252; 47 64); text = 'R'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x798cfe20>>
2014-11-26 15:18:18.358 Rave[3923:340203] Background: <UIView: 0x798d5d30; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x798cfdf0>>

Comment: I also just printed the color for the UILabel and I'm getting null: 2014-11-26 15:23:13.464 Rave[3962:342332] Letter R Color: (null) I'm also checking the background color and I'm getting: 2014-11-26 15:23:13.467 Rave[3962:342332] Background Color: UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 1 1 1. When changing it within the method the UIDeviceRGBColorSpace is changing just not being displayed on the simulator.

Comment: You could try using the layer property of the views. And/or calling `setNeedsDisplay:YES` on both objects. As rdelmar said, you need to make sure that your letterR and backgroundView are not nil.

Comment: I tried to do [letterR setNeedsDisplay]; [backgroundView setNeedsDisplay]; after modifying the colors and nothing happened.

Comment: Your code seems to be absolutely correct.

This strange and annoying thing happened with me too in iOS8 at one place.

Seems like a bug with apple.
I got this bug for a button's title label only.

To verify that this is some kind of bug only, what I did was made another label and assigned it the color i wanted to give to my required label 
    
        -- self.myButton.titleLabel.textColor = label.textColor; 
 
To my Surprise it worked. I ll suggest you try this way once.

Comment: That did not work either once I created a button. I am primarily trying to work with labels and not buttons though.

Comment: Anyone have any other suggestions?